# using event.preventDefault() in GSAP draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable, gsap

I have a GSAP animated widget(scrolling area) which work on an embedded browser. I am using GSAP draggable with snap points for the swiping animation. In side the draggable function, I need a `event.preventDefault();` while swiping happens. For this I used

```
onDrag: function () {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

But this is not working. When I check logs, it seems that the onDrag is working perfectly and only the `event.preventDefault();` is not working. I think it is because of the `event` object. Then I tried

```
onDrag: function () {
   $('#scroller').on("mousemove", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
   });
}
```

On this time it work perfectly. But because of the performance issues, we are restricted to use move event.

Anyway to make the `event.preventDefault();` working with out using another mouse event?

Comment: What is the purpose of prevent Default there? do you have any more code in its children?
are you passing event to your onDrag arguments? You could also try event.stopImmediatePropatation();

Comment: @gugateider. the app is an automobile infotainment application and it runs on a touch device. When the scroll is in an end position and if the user continue to drag, then some action like 'drag and select text' happens there. To prevent this, we are using event.preventDefault(); Unfortunately, I am not able to share a minimal code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can't you just check the position of your element and act accordingly? I previously said onDragEnd but that won't work if the user carries on dragging.